# Fluentbit using terraform

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am using using below config for terraform helm deployment of fluent bit.
What's wrong in this? I want to log in separate log group for application, host and dataplane.

serviceAccount:
create: false
name: ${SA_Name}

config:

fluent-bit.conf: |

```
[SERVICE]
    Flush                     5
    Grace                     30
    Log_Level                 info
    Daemon                    off
    Parsers_File              parsers.conf
    HTTP_Server               On
    HTTP_Listen               0.0.0.0
    HTTP_Port                 2020
    storage.path              /var/fluent-bit/state/flb-storage/
    storage.sync              normal
    storage.checksum          off
    storage.backlog.mem_limit 5M
```

application-log.conf: |

```
[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 application.*
    Exclude_Path        /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*, /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*, /var/log/containers/aws-node*, /var/log/containers/kube-proxy*
    Path                /var/log/containers/*.log
    multiline.parser    docker, cri
    DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_container.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
    Skip_Long_Lines     On
    Refresh_Interval    10
    Rotate_Wait         30
    storage.type        filesystem


[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 application.*
    Path                /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*
    multiline.parser    docker, cri
    DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_log.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines     On
    Refresh_Interval    10


[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 application.*
    Path                /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*
    multiline.parser    docker, cri
    DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_cwagent.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines     On
    Refresh_Interval    10


[FILTER]
    Name                kubernetes
    Match               application.*
    Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
    Kube_Tag_Prefix     application.var.log.containers.
    Merge_Log           On
    Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
    K8S-Logging.Parser  On
    K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
    Labels              Off
    Annotations         Off
    Use_Kubelet         On
    Kubelet_Port        10250
    Buffer_Size         0

[OUTPUT]
    Name                cloudwatch_logs
    Match               application.*
    region              ${AWS_REGION}
    log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/application
    auto_create_group   true
    extra_user_agent    container-insights
```

dataplane-log.conf: |

```
[INPUT]
    Name                systemd
    Tag                 dataplane.systemd.*
    Systemd_Filter      _SYSTEMD_UNIT=docker.service
    Systemd_Filter      _SYSTEMD_UNIT=containerd.service
    Systemd_Filter      _SYSTEMD_UNIT=kubelet.service
    DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/systemd.db
    Path                /var/log/journal
    Read_From_Tail      On

[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 dataplane.tail.*
    Path                /var/log/containers/aws-node*, /var/log/containers/kube-proxy*
    multiline.parser    docker, cri
    DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_dataplane_tail.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
    Skip_Long_Lines     On
    Refresh_Interval    10
    Rotate_Wait         30
    storage.type        filesystem


[FILTER]
    Name                modify
    Match               dataplane.systemd.*
    Rename              _HOSTNAME                   hostname
    Rename              _SYSTEMD_UNIT               systemd_unit
    Rename              MESSAGE                     message
    Remove_regex        ^((?!hostname|systemd_unit|message).)*$

[FILTER]
    Name                aws
    Match               dataplane.*
    imds_version        v2

[OUTPUT]
    Name                cloudwatch_logs
    Match               dataplane.*
    region              ${AWS_REGION}
    log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/dataplane
    auto_create_group   true
    extra_user_agent    container-insights
```

host-log.conf: |

```
[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 host.dmesg
    Path                /var/log/dmesg
    Key                 message
    DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_dmesg.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines     On
    Refresh_Interval    10


[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 host.messages
    Path                /var/log/messages
    Parser              syslog
    DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_messages.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines     On
    Refresh_Interval    10


[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 host.secure
    Path                /var/log/secure
    Parser              syslog
    DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_secure.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines     On
    Refresh_Interval    10


[FILTER]
    Name                aws
    Match               host.*
    imds_version        v2

[OUTPUT]
    Name                cloudwatch_logs
    Match               host.*
    region              ${AWS_REGION}
    log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/host
    auto_create_group   true
    extra_user_agent    container-insights
```

parsers.conf: |

```
[PARSER]
    Name                syslog
    Format              regex
    Regex               ^(?<time>[^ ]* {1,2}[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-]*)(?:\[(?<pid>[0-9]+)\])?(?:[^\:]*\:)? *(?<message>.*)$
    Time_Key            time
    Time_Format         %b %d %H:%M:%S

[PARSER]
    Name                container_firstline
    Format              regex
    Regex               (?<log>(?<="log":")\S(?!\.).*?)(?<!\\)".*(?<stream>(?<="stream":").*?)".*(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\w*).*(?=})
    Time_Key            time
    Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ

[PARSER]
    Name                cwagent_firstline
    Format              regex
    Regex               (?<log>(?<="log":")\d{4}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[ T]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?!\.).*?)(?<!\\)".*(?<stream>(?<="stream":").*?)".*(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\w*).*(?=})
    Time_Key            time
    Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ
```

Terraform, right format

Comment: Hi Abhi, and welcome to stack overflow. You've got this a bit backwards: you're supposed to tell us what's wrong, not ask us what's wrong